# Prevent hand ache during workout

Tags: strength-training, pain, hands

I've recently started to enjoy working out. However, my hands often feel achey and fatigued after a good workout (I mainly use various dumbbell exercises). How can I help avoid this?

Comment: How long is your training, and, what type(s) of exercise do you perform?  Please provide specific details.

Comment: @rrirower About an hour of various dumbbell exercises; curls, rows, etc. It's really just holding a dumbbell that causes the fatigue in my hands.

Comment: Is there any way you can switch the dumbells up? Barbell rows instead of DB rows, EZ Bar curls instead of DB curls, machines for isolation?

Answer (score 1):

IF they are truly feeling achey and fatigued then you can reduce the amount of fatigue by continuing to do what you do. As you train you will be developing your muscles involved in gripping the weight.

You could use straps or chalk to help hold the weights in your hand but you should try specifically training your grip first.

These answers give great information on how to train your grip:

[How do I improve my grip?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15357/how-do-i-improve-my-grip)

[Low-tech grip strength exercises](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/297/low-tech-grip-strength-exercises)

[How to improve left hand grip strength?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18736/how-to-improve-left-hand-grip-strength)

TL;DR Train your grip strength specifically.

Comment: what is TL;DR Train?

Comment: Internet acronym (Too Long, Didn't Read). Its a summary of the above (usually large) text in a few words.

Answer (score 1):

As you are recently started, as I read from above, I would say that the fatigue is something very normal. Your ligaments and tendons of your hands are going through a process of adoption.

I personally would avoid grip helping utilities until you really start training with heavy weights, as your muscles are taking less time to get used to the stress as your tendons and bones and you will probably cause more issues then avoiding them.

My recommendation would be to rotate the workouts to include an exercise without using 'grip' specific movements ex. Push-ups, sit ups etc. 
Taking more rest inbetween workouts helps too.

Answer (score 0):

> I've recently started to enjoy working out.

then On the answer of this question below, you will find useful info regarding how to improve your grip:

[Painful grip on deadlift and lat pulldown](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/painful-grip-on-deadlift-and-lat-pulldown?rq=1)

> After some time though,

you might find out that you enjoy more lifting heavier weights (some of us do)
then for the rows ([like one arm dumbbell rows for instance](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/31796/one-arm-dumbell-bent-over-row-is-it-a-complete-exercise-for-the-back)) I would try [weight lifting straps](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=shop&q=weight%20lifting%20straps), they will reduce the strength you need to put on your grip.

for the pushing exercises, like dumbbell presses,
I would try [liquid chalk](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=liquid%20chalk%20bodybuilding), it helps with your grip.

Comment: The top answer on that final link contradicts your suggestions...

Comment: @JJosaur I have change it a little bit to add different factors

Comment: Chalk is fine for both pulling and pushing.